# Как превратить obj файл в exe?

Tags: nasm

Я попробовал программировать на ассемблере NASM. Написал прогу в файле формата asm. Превратил файл из формата asm в obj, но когда я пытаюсь из формата obj превратить в exe с помощью GoLink, возникает ошибка:
Error!
A source file is in OMF format which is not supported (Hello.obj)
Output file not made
[image: Командная строка]

Comment: Возьмите FASM. Синтаксис почти такой-же, зато с компиляцией нет никаких проблем - нажал F9 и получил на выходе exe

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса